# Changing custom label in R

Tags: r

I am using soil texture package.
Currently I am using below code for my label. I have 10 data so currently it will give me a,b,c and so on. I want to change five of them to "T" and five of them to "NT". I would really appreciate your help. THank you

```
labelz <- letters[1:dim(my.data)[1]]

geo <- TT.plot(class.sys="USDA.TT")


TT.text(tri.data = my.data,geo = geo,labels = labelz,font = 2,col = "blue")
```

dummy data

```
my.data <- data.frame(
"CLAY" = c(05,60,15,05,25,05,25,45,65,75),
"SILT" = c(05,08,15,25,55,85,65,45,15,15),
"SAND" = c(90,32,70,70,20,10,10,10,20,10))
```

This command will show you the map

```
TT.plot(
class.sys = "HYPRES.TT",
tri.data = my.data,
main = "Soil texture data"
)
```

After this you can use the label code.
Packagae name soiltexture

Comment: Please provide reproducible example for us to assist with your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @AdamQuek Sorry. updated

Comment: Thanks for the updae. The example you have given 12 data-points, while you're asking to change the label to 5 as "T" and 5 as "NT"? Please clarify.

Comment: @AdamQuek Sorry. That was dummy file not my actual data. I have edited it to 10 data points.